# get innerText from getelementbyid in webview after webview is done loading

Tags: android, webview

Currently in my `onCreate` I have

```
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            if (progress == 100) {


                // get the innerText from user_id_firebase ID and put it in my db
                FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");

                myRef.setValue("Done Loading!");
            }
        }
    });
```

This ensures me that my webview has finished loading all the html. At this point I need to get the innerText of a element by it's id `user_id_firebase` so I can write it into my firebase DB. Trouble I am having is finding code on stack that will work inside my `setWebChromeClient`

I was looking at this and putting it in under `if (progress == 100) {` but

```
webView.evaluateJavascript(
        "(function() { return ('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('user_id_firebase')[0].innerHTML+'</html>'); })();",
        new ValueCallback<String>() {
@Override
public void onReceiveValue(String html) {
        Log.d("HTML", html);
        // code here
        }
        });
```

but I am getting

```
Variable 'webView' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final
```

Which honesty I am new to Android Studio so anyone have some wisdom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are trying to access to field inside inner the anonymous class. Java doesn't allow to do that. Simple solutions make your webView variable final or declare like class field.

```
final WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView)
```

Example from CLI application
[image]